# Mockito's thenCallRealMethod , not calling public method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to call the real method in my testing class.
there are two methods one is public void m2() and another private void m3() in mapper class.
but here only private method gets execute and public method doesn't gets call.
Sample code is like.

```
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    Mapper mapper;

    public void m1(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
        mapper.m1(s);
    }
}

public class Mapper {

    public String m1(String s){
        System.out.println("inside m1 method" +s);
        m2();
        m3();
        return s;
    }

    public void m2(){
        System.out.println("inside m2 public method");
    }

    private void m3(){
        System.out.println("insid m3 private method");
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Testing {

    @Mock
    Mapper mapper;

    @InjectMocks
    Service service;


    @Test
    public void test(){
    when(mapper.m1(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenCallRealMethod();

    service.m1("Check");
    }

    /**
     * @param m1
     */

}
```

Comment: first of all, you have 2 public methods and 1 private. Secondly you don't mock the second public method, that's why you don't get an output for that method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public method is not called because you don't instruct mock to do so.

Private method is called because mockito doesn't affect private methods (You have to summon dark magic of PowerMock to do so).

Comment: Thanks @talex ,very helpful in debugging.